# Mint plant with white spots and black dots. Possible insect culprit

Tags: leaves, insects, bugs, mint

My mint plant has been getting white spots with black small dots all over it. I've cut them all down at some point, they always start to grow/sprout again perfectly without any spots, but soon enough the spots always reappear all over the leaves.

I've seen some small insects flying around the plant. I've managed to get one and look closely with a USB microscope.

Here are the white spots:

[image]

[image]

And here is the insect under the microscope:

[image]
[image]
[image]

PS: I've also checked the leaves with the spots under the microscope, but couldn't see anything special, it's like a white discoloration white some black dust on top.

**QUESTION**

Does anybody know what insect this is? Could it be the culprit of the white spots on my mint plant? How can I get rid of it?

There was a rose plant nearby that was getting these spots as well, but I've split them apart and the rose now seems to be doing fine without the mint plant around.

Comment: Nice pictures!  Hope when I ask a question about bugs I'll be able to get an image that is just half as nice as these.  Bonus points for microscope shots!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've posted a very good image from which it's easy to see this is a Ligurian Leafhopper. The black dots are likely frass (the insect's poo) and they feed by sucking the sap from the leaves and stems of the host plant, image and information here http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/VEG/LEAF/Ligurian_leafhopper.HTM

They will happily use mint as a host plant, and it's likely an adult has laid its eggs on the leaves, but control is difficult. As the name implies,the adults are capable of hopping, Regular treatment with neem spray should provide some control, otherwise a physical intervention such as shaking or picking them off will help, though when they are developing, they're difficult to see.

Comment: Thanks. And the whites spots are also probably cause by them, right? From eating the leaves?

Comment: Yes, most likely that's the cause of the whitened areas, though I would expect them to shrivel and go brown over time.